# Django UpdateView: Set dropdowns to selected value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I just recently started using class based views and am still clueless what the right way to preselect the right dropdown value is.

I have a simple UpdateView like this:

```
class SomeUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = SomeModel
    form_class = SomeCreateForm
    permission_required = 'app.some_model'
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    raise_exception = True

    def form_valid(self, form):
        from_page = self.request.GET.get('from')
        if from_page:
            self.success_url = self.request.GET.get('from')
        else:
            self.success_url = "/somewhere/"
        return super(SomeUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

While this works and it also fills `CharFields` etc., dropdowns stay unselected, making it really uncomfortable to use. What I would want is that the currently selected field of the object is already selected when you are going to edit it (UpdateView).

The `form` used is just a standard `ModelForm` with fields defined. The field itself is a `Foreignkey`.

I have tried to use `get_initial(self)` etc. to set the dropdown value, but with no success.

Comment: The right dropdown value for the given model should already be filled in for you if you're working with an instance of a model (which UpdateView does). Does the instance you're displaying have a valid value set for the given foreign key?

Comment: Yes, it should be right. I just checked again and I can access the selected foreignkey through it. Neither UpdateView nor doing it via the admin panel throws any errors either. But both of them don't keep it selected. ManyToMany fields on the other hand show the relations properly.

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution for my problem:

Inside the class:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(MyObjectUpdate, self).get_initial()
    try:
        field1 = self.get_object().field1
        field2 = self.get_object().field2
    except:
        pass
    else:
        initial['field1'] = field1.pk
        initial['field2'] = field2.pk
    return initial
```

This fixed my problem and the UpdateView extending class now returns my to be edited form with the right values selected in its dropdowns. I am not sure if it is the right/best way to do it though.

Comment: What is MyObjectUpdate?

Comment: You don't need to include the class and self in super() in Python 3. `super().get_initial()` would work.